# add a class to randomly selected tags in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have stored 5 **random** custom tag elements named **logocon** from the DOM. I want to add a class to each of those randomly selected tags only. here is the code that gets 5 random tags. I tried .addClass() but it does not work.

```
  randomElements = jQuery("logocon").get().sort(function(){ 
        return Math.round(Math.random())-0.5
    }).slice(0,5)
```

Comment: If you actually have something like: `<logocon>This is a non-standard element</logocon>`, you should seriously consider using `<div>` or `<span>`. If you do not have any non-standard HTML, then add the relevant HTML as well,

Comment: Please add an excerpt of your actual HTML code.

Answer (score 0):

`randomElements` is an array of DOM elements, not a jQuery collection. You can wrap it with `$()` to convert it to a jQuery collection so you can use `.addClass()`.

```
$(randomElements).addClass('newclass');
```